# Seeking Guidance Initially, but Successfully Proved Later

Tags: support, asking-questions, self-answer

I posted a one question on Math Stack Exchange, completed most of the process, but got stuck. Later, I figured it out and proved the question. Should I delete my post, finish the solution or Should I remove the question?

Comment: You can't prove a question, any more than you can eat an alphabet, or interrogate a sofa. You can prove a theorem, you can answer a question, but you can't prove a question. If you have been able to answer a question posted on mathstackexchange, you should post an answer as an answer, regardless of who posted the question.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an uncommon experience which is exactly why we have the option to answer our own questions. I would recommend posting your solution as an answer to your question. This allows other people to learn from your work if they happen to have the same question.